# Como fazer um background de um elemento em SVG de maneira decente?

Tags: css, svg

Desenvolvo sites que possuem o logo da empresa em **SVG**, mas queria saber como testar de forma fácil ou forçar para que substitua o **SVG** quando o navegador não suportar. 
Assim eu poderia ter o logo feito em **PNG** para substituir.

> Geralmente coloco o SGV como background de um elemento com
>   visibilidade em bloco e faço um CSS alternativo para IE8 e menores,
>   estou agindo corretamente?

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo que como você faz? No [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) talvez?

Comment: @Fernando, um exemplo de como faço com SVG está no link: http://jsfiddle.net/cZ33j/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Se alterar a *markup* for uma opção

<sup>Estou a [responder em separado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/782/223) porque tratam-se de duas soluções distintas com implicações distintas e de certa forma esta é uma resposta extensa que carece a sua independência.</sup>

Através da alteração da *markup* que estás actualmente a utilizar, podes lidar com a questão do suporte ao SVG sem precisares de incrementar a tua folha de estilos ou o ficheiro de script com linhas de código que só vão servir uma pequena percentagem dos visitantes.

## [SVG and  tag tricks](http://lynn.ru/examples/svg/en.html)

A solução apresentada tem como principio o facto de que os navegadores fazem da tag `image` um pseudônimo para a tag `img`, como é explicado em [Having fun with `<image>`](http://jakearchibald.com/2013/having-fun-with-image/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> da autoria de Jake Archibald onde podemos ler:

> - Firefox aliases 'image' to 'img' at parse-time
> - Chrome & Safari alias 'image' to 'img' at element-creation time
> - IE aliases 'image' to 'img' throughout the runtime

Que (+/-) traduzido:

> - Firefox converte `image` para `img` ao fazer o parse
> - Chrome & Safari convertem `image` para `img` ao criarem o elemento
> - IE converte `image` para `img` no decorrer do processamento

Mediante isto, a ideia é fazer uso da tag `svg` com uma `image` no seu interior onde damos a indicação dos dois ficheiros a utilizar, o SVG se suportado e a imagem de fallback para o caso de ser necessária.

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
    <image xlink:href="http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.svg" src="http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.png" width="400" height="400"/>
</svg>
```

A questão aqui é se podes ou não albergar a alteração da *markup* que é evidentemente necessária para aplicar esta solução.

Assumindo que sim, eis como ficariam as coisas para o mesmo efeito:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/a3tzB/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="logo">
        <svg width="500" height="500">
            <image xlink:href="http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.svg" src="http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.png" width="500" height="500"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    display:block;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin:40px;
}
.bg{
    background-color:#333;
}
```

**Resultado**

O resultado após adicionar a markup para o SVG e após remover CSS agora desnecessário, fica como pode ser visto em baixo ou no JSFiddle:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Obtemos assim o mesmo ambiente visual que inicialmente era primariamente conseguido recorrendo a definições de CSS.

**Nota:**

Conforme podemos ver em [SVG Fallbacks da autoria de Chris Coyier](http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> cujo mesmo fala sobre os links já presentes nesta resposta e na técnica aqui sugerida:

[image: Análise no IE]

No Internet Explorer podemos ver que ambas as imagens são requisitadas ao servidor. Contudo, apenas uma chega a ser transferida, a imagem não necessária vem com 0KB, o que nos diz que o navegador a dada altura cancela a requisição por entender que afinal não precisa da imagem.

Comment: Parabéns, exatamente como eu necessitava. Obrigado.

Comment: @Zuul Muita boa resposta, vai me auxiliar em implementações futuras. Parabéns (Esse português de Portugal, que ferra... rsrs)

Answer (score 5):

#### Se JavaScript / jQuery for uma opção

Podes perguntar ao navegador se ele suporta ou não SVG e mediante a resposta agir em conformidade:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/g7LA4/)

```
/**
 * Detecta suporte ao SVG
 */
function suportas_SVG() {
    return !!document.createElementNS && !!document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', "svg").createSVGRect;
}

// Se não tem suporte ...
if (!suportas_SVG())
    $('.logo').css({
      "background-image" : "url(http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.png)"
    });
```

<sup>O código na função sugerida encontra-se no código-fonte do [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que seria a minha recomendação se tiveres que fazer muitas verificações desse género para vários tipos de suporte.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Se você faz um hack `css` tipo isso:

```
/* hack css para navegadores que não suportam svg */
background: url(http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.png) top center no-repeat;
background: url(http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.svg) top center no-repeat;
```

Essa é uma maneira descente para mim. (no minimo inevitável).

**EDIT 1**

Tem muitas maneiras, uma que talvez se adeque ao que você quer seja essa:

```
background-image: url(http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.svg); /* Qualquer Browser */
background-image /*\**/: url(http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.png)\9; /* Internet Explorer 8 */
*background-image: url(http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.png); /* Internet Explorer 6 e 7 */
_background-image: url(http://www.quatrocubos.com.br/img/qq.png); /* Internet Explorer 6 */
```

Obs: você não vai está cobrindo todos os navegadores, você só estará cobrindo os IEs.

Comment: Quando eu faço isso eu gero uma requisição para um arquivo PNG mesmo que ele não seja utilizado. Nesse caso ainda é melhor ter um CSS separado com regras que sobrescrevam as originais, pelo menos somente o IE vai ter mais requisições que os outros navegadores. Se você possui mais alguma ideia me envie. :D

Comment: @2madera veja meu edit 1

Comment: Se é para focar somente no IE como exceção, também é possível usar conditional comments para incluir um CSS específico.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim mais acho esses hacks, mais elegantes (se é que pode chamar hack css de elegante)

Comment: Eu acho o contrário, rs! Mas aí é questão de opinião.

Comment: Muito bom mesmo, vou experimentar pra ver.